# Why (lambda () (run-hooks 'foo)) instead of just 'foo?

Tags: hooks

I am studying the following code snippet taken from [prelude-c.el](https://github.com/bbatsov/prelude/blob/master/modules/prelude-c.el):

```
;; taken from prelude-c.el

(defun prelude-makefile-mode-defaults ()
  (whitespace-toggle-options '(tabs))
  (setq indent-tabs-mode t))

(setq prelude-makefile-mode-hook 'prelude-makefile-mode-defaults)

(add-hook 'makefile-mode-hook (lambda ()
                                (run-hooks 'prelude-makefile-mode-hook)))
```

The author defined a function named `prelude-makefile-mode-defaults`, then made `prelude-makefile-mode-hook` an alias to it, and finally run it with `lambda` and `run-hooks`. This looks tedious to me. In my humble opinion, it can be simplified to

```
(defun prelude-makefile-mode-defaults ()
  (whitespace-toggle-options '(tabs))
  (setq indent-tabs-mode t))

(add-hook 'makefile-mode-hook #'prelude-makefile-mode-defaults)
```

Now it is much clearer, and they *appears* to have the same effect, but of course, the authors of prelude.el must be much more sophisticated than me, who is just a beginner. Is there any hidden advantage of writing down all these seemingly redundant code?

Comment: Good question.  I much prefer your version, and I don't see why the Prelude would use the other form.

Comment: @Stefan I'm curious is there a difference between `(foo)` and `(run-hooks foo)`? If they are equivalent, then the function `run-hooks` would be pointless...

Comment: I think the intent of the author is to provide a hook that can be used for customization. Having a way to guarantee that your own hooks run close after ones from `prelude` might be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the reason for this indirection is that it allows users of the package to override the package provided defaults by changing the value of `prelude-makefile-mode-hook`. The final component of the name `prelude-makefile-mode-defaults` is a strong hint in this direction, I think. But of course, only the original package author can give a definitive answer.